# The space $H^s(\mathbb R)$ and the embedding in $L^p_{loc}(\mathbb R)$: for which $p$?

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, fractional-calculus, fractional-sobolev-spaces

Let $s\in (0, 1)$ and consider the fractionl Sobolev space $H^s(\mathbb R)$ (see e.g. https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0007449711001254).

Let $(A, ||\cdot||)$ be a Banach space and suppose that $A\subset H^s(\mathbb R)$, with the embedding being continuous, namely there exists $c$ depending on $s$ such that $||u||_{H^s}\le c||u||$ for any $u\in A$.

Assume that $(u_n)\subset A$ is bounded in $A$. The question is: Is it possible to conclude that, up to a renamed subsequence,
$$u_n\to u\quad\text{ in } L^p_{loc}(\mathbb R) \text{ for some $p$}?$$

There is any $p$ for which it holds independently on the choice of $s\in (0, 1)$? (I mean $s>1/2$ or $s<1/2$) Could you please provide a reference?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes, this is Rellich-Kondrachov theorem. It will work for any $p$ smaller than the critical Sobolev embedding, and so for any $p\leq 2$ independently of $s$.

Comment: Notice that you could directly say $A= H^s$, it would give an equivalent question ... no need to introduce this $A$ at all.

Comment: @LL3.14 thank you for your comments. Did I understand correctly that the embedding il $L^p_{loc}(\mathbb R)$ holds for any $p\in [1, 2^*_s]$?

Comment: Or is it $p\in [2, 2*_s]$?

Comment: Also, if $s>1/2$, is the embedding true for any $p\in [2, +\infty]$?

Comment: I apologize for my multiple questions. You can post them as answer, so I can accept it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @LL3.14, one last question is about the embedding of the $L^p_{loc}(\mathbb R)$ spaces. Is that true that if $p\in [2, 2^*_s]$, then $L^p_{loc}(\mathbb R)$ is continuously embedded in $L^2_{loc}(\mathbb R)$?

Comment: Yes, for any $p>2$, as on bounded domains ...